# Background image fix doesn't work Css/jquerymobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

the main page of my App has a content that is scrollable and I need to make the image background fixed. That' s the code of my css:

```
ui-overlay-e {
    border: 1px solid #f7c942 /*{e-body-border}*/;
    color: #222 /*{e-body-color}*/;
    text-shadow: 0 /*{e-body-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{e-body-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{e-body-shadow-radius}*/ #fff /*{e-body-shadow-color}*/;
    background-image:url("../img/biografia_bg.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

But it doesn't work, the background scroll. I don't understand why.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use the "fix" tag unless you're talking about FIX protocol.  I also fixed your other tags to useful ones that people will actually follow.  Take note -- tags help the right people notice your question!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment, how I can solve my problem ?

Comment: My comment was about the tags that are attached to each question, which help people find relevant questions.  (Sorry, I don't have experience with mobile development myself; I only looked at your question because you originally tagged it "fix".)

Comment: Ok fix is an error, but is not possible change the title, the right word is fixed, sorry

Comment: Dude, I'm only talking about the tags (see [this pic](http://i.imgur.com/aDbVJZn.png)).  You can still use the word "fix" in the title and stuff.  You're good.